# Laravel 5: passing variable into subject

Tags: email, laravel

I am using Laravel's mail class and would like to pass variable into subject. Here is my code:

```
public function send()
{
    $offer = Offer::find($id)->toArray();

    Mail::send('offerMail', $offer, function($message) {
        $message->to('some@email.com');
        $message->subject('Offer No.' . $offer['code']);
    });
}
```

I am getting

```
Undefined variable: offer
```

within line where subject is defined.

Comment: what does your controller look like?

Comment: Too long to paste it here.

Comment: I've gotten this error before for me it was that the case of the controller and the model didn't match

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't forget to inject your outer variables into Closure's scope.

```
Mail::send('offerMail', $offer, function($message) use ($offer) {
    $message->to('some@email.com');
    $message->subject('Offer No.' . $offer['code']);
});
```

You can see examples about this under *Example 3* section in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-188).